# How to initiate counter when new item is added

Tags: java, arrays, counter

I have array as seen below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List asList = Arrays.asList("banner","carousel","banner","carousel","banner");
    Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(asList);
    for(String s: mySet){

     System.out.println(s + " " +Collections.frequency(asList,s));

    }

}
```

Output:

```
carousel 2
banner 3
```

DesiredOutput:

```
banner0
carousel0
banner1
carousel1
banner2
```

Please let me know what needs to be done in this case.

Comment: In your code snippet there is no counter. What do you mean?

Comment: If you need to maintain the insertion order a List seems more appropriate than a Set.

Comment: there are many different ways to achieve the functionality you are looking for, consider modifying your `for-each` loop to be a standard `for` loop with an iterator. You may consider using if conditions and adding another loop inside your outer `for` loop.

Comment: I would use a HashMap<String,Int> to remember the current count of the string element, and increase it each time. However this looks like a school/university assignment, it would be wrong to just write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this simple change : here we do a sub list which counts only till the current loop item.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List asList = Arrays.asList("banner", "carousel", "banner", "carousel", "banner");
        for(int i=0;i<asList.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(asList.get(i)+" : " + Collections.frequency(asList.subList(0,i), asList.get(i)));
        }
    }
```

Output :

```
banner : 0
carousel : 0
banner : 1
carousel : 1
banner : 2
```

Comment: I assume the downvotes are because the solution is very inefficient. Creating a sublist and calculating a frequency each iteration seems like a very bad design choice imho.

Comment: @Keppil Thanks that helps. FYI I'm not creating a subList every time just using the cut list.

Comment: @StackFlowed   

can you please help me in this.
I need to put this inside map with incremental keys like below:


`0 :banner   0: carousel    1: banner    1: carousel    2: banner`

Comment: @MananKapoor Please create a new question ... Cause this solution answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the `add` method to print the frequency write before adding:

```
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("banner", "carousel", "banner", "carousel", 
                                   "banner");
// ...
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
for(String s : asList) {
    addAndPrint(s, mySet);
}

private static final addAndPrint(String s, Collectection<String> c) {
    System.out.println(s + " " + Collections.frequency(c, s));
    c.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve this by using a Map:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("banner", "carousel", "banner", "carousel", "banner");
        final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (final String s : asList)
        {

            if (!map.containsKey(s))
            {
                map.put(s, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
            }
            System.out.println(s + " " + map.get(s));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using iterator and the std for loop instead of the cutom set. If you always have "Carousel" and "Banner" as items then declare two counters and encounter them when each of them is encountered. Below is a snippet

```
 List asList = Arrays.asList("banner","carousel","banner","carousel","banner");
        int countb = 0;
        int countc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < asList.size(); i++) {
            if (asList.get(i).equals("banner")) {
                countb++;
                System.out.print("banner"+countb+"\n");
            } else if (asList.get(i).equals("carousel")) {
                countc++;
                System.out.print("carousel"+countc+"\n");

            }
        }
```